Quickchart ticks.callback for labelling does not work when shortening url
I want to make a chart with double y-axes which have each callback for y labeling using quickchart rendering.
It is well generated if I used the below config in "https://quickchart.io/chart?c={config}"
(well generated chart)

Because the length of this url is quite long, I want to shorten this url using "https://quickchart.io/chart/create" here.
However, If I use the create post method for shortening url, the callback does not work.
(Chart with shorten url)

Is there a way to use ticks.callback when I use create short url?
Config is the below:
{
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
    datasets: [
      {
        label: 'My First dataset',
        backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
        borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
        data: [93, -29, -17, -8, 73, 98, 40],
        fill: false,
        yAxisID: 'y1',

      },
      {
        label: 'My Second dataset',
        fill: false,
        backgroundColor: 'rgb(54, 162, 235)',
        borderColor: 'rgb(54, 162, 235)',
        data: [20, 85, -79, 93, 27, -81, -22],
        yAxisID: 'y2',

      },
    ],
  },
  options: {
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: 'Chart.js Line Chart',
    },
    scales:{
      yAxes: [
        {
          id: 'y1',
          display: true,
          position: 'left',
          stacked: true,
          ticks: {
                callback: function(value, index, ticks) {
                  return '$' + value;
                }
              }

        },
        {
          id: 'y2',
          display: true,
          position: 'right',
          ticks: {
                callback: function(value, index, ticks) {
                  return '$' + value;
                }
              }
        },
      ],
    }
  },
}


it says something about special steps to take if you are using JavaScript in your chart.  read

Thanks James.It works when send the chart parameter as a string, not as a JSON object as you linked.
